# How to call ajax on jsp page load to fetch data from database with the help of servlet (not on form submit)

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp

I want to fetch data from database on jsp page with the help of servlet using ajax call.

ajax call

```
$(document).ready(function(){
         var sid = $('#surveyId').val();
          alert(sid);
          $.ajax({
                    url: "getEditSurvey", 
                    data:{
                        sid:sid
                        },
                    success: function(data){
                        alert(response);
                        $("#displayEdit").html(response);          
                }
                    
          });
  });
```

jsp file

```
<input type="hidden" name="surveyId" id="surveyId" value="<%= request.getParameter("sid") %>" >
    <div id="displayEdit">
    
    </div>
```

My problem:

I am using this method to fetch data but it is displaying nothing Is this is right way to do this. I am new to ajax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ajax code looks right except there is a small mistake in your success function of your ajax code

The code inside your success function should be

```
alert(data);
$("#displayEdit").html(data);
```

If you see the success functions parameter the name is "data". That parameter will hold the data that your servlet will return.

Comment: Maybe the URL may not be right as you have mentioned a relative URL. Try adding a '/' in front of the URL. You can debug ajax easily by opening developer tools on chrome or firefox hit   f12 and look at the network tab

Comment: @sukhvirthapad is it posible to perform update query on retrieved data

Comment: @jyotsnashekhar you will have to create another ajax end point that takes that data and updates it.

Comment: @sukhvirthapad I printed the data in servlet. Jsp page unable to perform any update function on it